# Use $ vs # in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a weird question about '$' and '#', why doesn't the single '$' work?

The `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` version is 2.0.1.

```java
@Select("select * from user where user_id=#{userId}")
User findUserId(int userId);
```

That's ok

```java
@Select("select * from user where user_id=${userId}")
User findUserId(String userId);
```

There is an error:
`org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'userId' in 'class java.lang.String'`

I use `mybatis` configuration `useActualParamName=true`, so I don't need to apply `@Param`, if use `@Param`

```java
@Select("select * from user where user_id=${userId}")
User findUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

or at the same time use '#' and '$'

```java
@Select("select * from user where user_id=${userId} and status=#{status}")
User findUserId(String userId, int status);
```

That's ok.

Why does this happen？If not use `@Param`, the single '$' not work and throw exception?

Answer (score 1):

> In mybatis, #{variable} gets replaced with 'variable value' and ${variable} is replaced with variable value(without quotes).

In your case, if the value of userId is String, you get an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry. My problem may not have been clearly described